# Error al crear clave foranea de una tabla

Tags: laravel-5

Veran, tengo en mi proyecto una tabla Targeta con el siguiente código:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateTargetasTable extends Migration{
    public function up(){
        Schema::create('targetas', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('codigo');
            $table->integer('saldo');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down(){
        Schema::dropIfExists('targetas');
    }
}
```

Y se relaciona con la tabla User:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration{
    public function up(){
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table){
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->unsignedInteger('cuenta');
            $table->foreign('cuenta')->references('id')->on('targetas');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down(){
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

Pero me encuentro con esto al hacer la migración:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Que estare haciendo mal?

Edito: He añadido una foto con mis ficheros de creación de las tablas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: puedes mostrar por favor el código de la migración de tiendas pues el error te señala que la llave foránea esta mal

Comment: Cómo se llama tu archivo de php donde tienes el modelo de tu tabla tarjetas?

Comment: por favor actualiza tu pregunta con el código de las otras migraciones

Answer (score 1):

Como no me entraba bien la explicacion en los comentarios la agrego como respuesta, estoy bastante seguro que el motivo es el siguiente:

El problema viene porque se está queriendo crear una forenign key en relación a una tabla que no existe, en este caso `targetas`.

En la imagen que adjuntas se ve que se dropearon todas las tablas, se creo luego la tabla de migrations y luego se ejecuto la migracion de creacion de la tabla `Users` y que está tirando ese error, antes debería haberse ejecutado la migración que te crea la tabla `targetas` para luego poder usar su id como foránea en la tabla `User`.

Y esto seguramente se dió porque editaste directamente la migracion de la tabla `user` que te creo por default el comando `php artisan make:auth`

Laravel corre las migraciones en base a la fecha de creacion que tiene el nombre de la misma.

Si recién estas arrancando el proyecto la solución mas fácil es cambiar la fecha a la migracion de `targetas` para que se ejecuta antes que la de la tabla `user` y volver a correr las migraciones.

Espero que sea de utilidad, saludos.

**EDIT EN BASE A COMENTARIO**

@MiguelAlparez, no veo que hayas probado lo que te dije en mis comentarios, la migration de tu tabla `users` se llama `2014_10_15_000000_create_users_table.php` y la de tu tabla `targetas` `2018_03_14_etc_etc.php`, al menos en la foto que adjuntas no le has cambiado las fechas a los nombres de los archivos. Por lo tanto se sigue ejecutando la migración de la tabla `users` antes que la de tu tabla `targetas`.

Ponle este nombre a la migración de la tabla targetas y debería funcionar:

2013_01_01_000000_create_targetas_table.php

y luego corre lo siguiente (Ojo, Esto borra todas las tablas de tu base y vuelve a correr todas las migraciones):

`php artisan migrate:fresh`

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Es decir, como primero se crea User y luego la tabla targeta, eso me produce el error.

Comment: Dices que puedo hacer que primero se haga la otra tabla para que no de ese error. ¿Como se hace?

Comment: Reescribo el comentario porque el corrector del celular me cambio todas las palabras. Lo que preguntas está en la última parte de la respuesta. Las migraciones se ejecutan por el orden de la fecha que tienen el nombre de las mismas. Cambia las fechas en el nombre de las migraciones y vuelvelas a correr.

Comment: he probado lo que dices de cambiar la fecha que aparece en el nombre y el error persiste.

Comment: podrias volver a pegar otra imagen con el error? la migracion de la tabla se ejecuto en el orden adecuado?

Comment: he añadido una foto con la lista de ficheros de las tablas. A ver si eso te da una pista.

Comment: @MiguelAlparez te deje una respuesta que espero también te sea útil para checar el orden de las migraciones